# Pseudorandom Generator vs Constant Depth Circuits / Branching Programs

Tags: computational-complexity

Hi.

I am looking for a survey on the state of the art in pseudorandom generators vs

(1) constant depth circuits
and/or
(2) Branching Programs

For (1), is "Anindya De, Omid Etesami, Luca Trevisan and Madhur Tulsiani
Improved Pseudorandom Generators for Depth 2 Circuits" state of the art?

For (2), given that Barrington's theorem states that width-5 poly size branching programs = NC1 in power; what limited model of branching programs is studied in terms of fooling branching programs with pseudorandom generators?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess you'd get more and quicker responses at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

For (1), their result is for depth 2 Circuits and is the best known so far. For more general constant-depth circuit, you may want to look at

[Mark Braverman: Poly-logarithmic independence fools AC0 circuits](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mbraverm/FoolAC0v7.pdf)

Barrington proved width-5 poly size **multiple read** branching programs = NC1. But people usually only talk about fooling **read-once** branching programs, i.e. each variable is read at most once.